# How does Android Studio provide signature configuration during "Generate Signed Bundle / APK"?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, digital-signature

I'm curious around how this dialog interacts with the gradle build system:

[image: Generate Signed Bundle / APK Dialog]

When I complete the flow, it's able to inject the certificate into my build without requiring any modification to my `build.gradle` file.

How is it doing this?

Comment: checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline#sign_manually) article

Comment: Ah, so it's just doing a regular unsigned build and then signing it afterwards?

Comment: I guess so. At least it is one of the possible ways

Comment: I'd love to know if it's doing anything different, but I suppose this would be effectively the same as the whole dialog.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow me : I share with you screenshot**
*before generate any signin apk first check build gradle version and targetsdkversion*

[image: build option clicked]

[image: select APK option and next]

[image: if keystore file available then first remember your password]

[image: if keystore file not available then fill all information and don't forget created password. jks file extension]

[image: choose your keystore file, if already generated]

[image: release option select and create]

[image: successfully generated signed APK]

*please check this link also*
[signed APK information provide in build gradle file](https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline#sign_manually)

Comment: This is a low-effort answer. I'm not asking how to create a signed build.  I'm asking how the build signing dialogs interact with gradle.

Comment: oh , I am apologies sir.